# How to extract substring with Python Regex Exact Match

Tags: python, regex

I'm learning Python Regular Expression (re) to analyze twitter text.

Let's say I have twitter text like below and I only want to extract exactly '3/10' from txt.
Python return empty list [] in this case.

```
txt = "my mood is low 3/10. 05/01/2021 Tuesday"
re.findall('^\d+\/\d{2}$', txt)
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Or use `(?<!\S)\d+\/\d{2}(?!/)` https://regex101.com/r/DwnXit/1

Comment: Wrong are `^` and `$`. They mark the start and end of a line or string, in combination your regex only matches a full line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using anchors to match the whole line, you can use negative lookarounds to assert a whitespace boundary to the left, and not a `/` to the right to match `3/10` only.

```
(?<!\S)\d+\/\d{2}(?!/)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uCvgcA/1)

```
import re
txt = "my mood is low 3/10. 05/01/2021 Tuesday"
print(re.findall('(?<!\S)\d+\/\d{2}(?!/)', txt))
```

Output

```
['3/10']
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `^` and `$`

```
re.findall(r'\b\d+/\d{2}\b', txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [re docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

`^` *(Caret.) Matches the start of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches immediately after each newline.*

`$` *Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches before a newline. foo matches both ‘foo’ and ‘foobar’, while the regular expression foo$ matches only ‘foo’. More interestingly, searching for foo.$ in 'foo1\nfoo2\n' matches ‘foo2’ normally, but ‘foo1’ in MULTILINE mode; searching for a single $ in 'foo\n' will find two (empty) matches: one just before the newline, and one at the end of the string.*

This is not case in your example. You would need to use more advanced zero-length assertions.